# XCode file not compiling

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, linker, project

I'm getting the following two errors via xcode:

```
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/SQLite Toolbox/en.lproj/MainWindowController.m' of type file for architecture x86_64
```

Followed by:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MainWindowController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Previously my project was building just fine, but I attempted to do some localization. I had my `MainWindowController.xib` highlighted and choose the `localize` option.

After that, the project stopped compiling. It looks to me that for some reason XCode is refusing to compile my MainWindowController.m, but i'm not sure how to go about fixing that. (I have confirmed it does exist in the `Build Phase` `Compile Source` steps.

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds as if you inadvertently have localized the "MainWindowController.m" file.
The following steps worked in my test project to fix that situation:

- Remove "MainWindowController.m" from your project (using the "Remove Reference" option!)
- In the Finder, move "MainWindowController.m" from the "en.lproj" folder back to the main folder.
- Drag "MainWindowController.m" onto the Xcode project to add it again.

Comment: There I thought I had seen it all with 6 years of iOS programming I run into this #!@%!. Thank you for the solution.